# Why does the Django django.contrib.auth.authenticate need in-place arguments?

Tags: python, django, authentication

Why does the Django authenticate function work only with this?

```
user=authenticate(
        username=request.POST['username'],
        password=request.POST['password']
    )
```

And not with

```
user=authenticate(
        request.POST['username'],
        request.POST['password']
    )
```

Comment: because it doesnt understand which field django needs to compare with, as authenticate can be modified by custom auth backend where you can use email inplace of username, thus you need to pass the column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be many different authentication backends and they might use a different way of authentication than with username and password, i.e. some kind of token. To keep `authenticate()` method generic, it had to be implemented this way.
[Official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) says "It takes credentials as keyword arguments, *username* and *password* for the default case." The key part is: *for the default case*.
The only argument that can be given as positional argument is the optional `request` argument.